# Selecting columns - dataframes, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do you go about selecting a column in a Pandas Dataframe, where the column name depends on a value, which we have located in another dataframe  ?  For example, if [1,2,3..] are column names of dataframe 1 and [1,2,3..] are values of different cells in dataframe 2. How do you select a column in dataframe 1, by matching the column name with cell value in dataframe 2.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of inputs you have and output you wish.

Comment: `df1 = pd.DataFrame([list('abc')], [0], [1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[2, 3, 1]))

df1

   1  2  3
0  a  b  c

df2


   A
0  2
1  3
2  1
`
If these are the inputs. I am selecting the value '2' (0,A) from df2 and want to access data in df1 such that the row index is '0' and column name is = '2' (0,A) (the variable that I've accessed from df1 as a cell value). So, the answer is 'b' (0,2) You can check the example in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([list('abc')], [0], [1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[2, 3, 1]))

df1

   1  2  3
0  a  b  c

df2

   A
0  2
1  3
2  1

df1[df2.A]

   2  3  1
0  b  c  a
```

---

**response to comment**

```
df1.loc[0, df2.loc[0, 'A']]

'b'
```

---

```
df1.at[0, df2.at[0, 'A']]

'b'
```

---

```
df1.get_value(0, df2.get_value(0, 'A'))

'b'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Although, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try and be more clear by taking your own given example (thanks btw). `df1 = pd.DataFrame([list('abc')], [0], [1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[2, 3, 1]))

df1

   1  2  3
0  a  b  c

df2


   A
0  2
1  3
2  1
`
If these are the inputs. I am selecting the value '2' (0,A) from df2 and want to access data in df1 such that the row index is '0' and column name is = '2' (0,A) (the variable that I've accessed from df1 as a cell value). So, the answer is 'b' (0,2)

Comment: I'm sorry, piRSquared, but none of the solutions seem to work. I had already tried the first one, it didn't work. I tried the other two. The "get_value" one returned me an error " KeyError : 201306" "201306" is the value that I was reading from one dataframe and this was the column name of another dataframe. `testValue = submit.get_value(1000001, third.get_value(1000001, 'Date1'))` `#1000001 is the index and 201306 is the value, third.get_value(1000001, 'Date1') returns`

Comment: I converted the value to string with "str(...)" and it worked. Thank You so much

Comment: @Aryan please consider accepting this answer.  Thanks [**WhatToDoWhenSomeoneAnswers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)